# Broken Slave MySQL : How To Fix MySQL Replication (BINLOG) error in the Slave?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, master-slave-replication, mysqlbinlog, gtid

Before we start I can give some info about the versions,

Ubuntu - 14.04, MySQL - 5.5

I have successfully configured the Master-Slave replication with two EC2 Ubuntu instances. My master is in Ubuntu 14 and slave is in Ubuntu 18. The replication was successful and the slave was replicating data for the last 3-4 days. But, suddenly my slave(Ubuntu 18) stopped replication with a query error.

**Error Message :** Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '11379183' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'test'. Query: 'INSERT INTO testTable (id,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6) VALUES(22,"5","429438","1592499300","1","8","1")'

> Slave_IO_Running: Yes
>
> Slave_SQL_Running: No

I have tried,

> STOP SLAVE;
>
> SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;
>
> START SLAVE;

It has helped me for some time. but the replication is broken again.

How can we resolve this kind of replication errors? Is there any automated method for fixing the broken slave?

Is GTID based replication possible with MySQL 5.5? I think GTID is available from MySQL version 5.6?

Answer (score 1):

The pt-slave-repair is a supplement to the original pt-slave-restart tool, providing automatic repair for erroneous data in MySQL master-slave replication, as well as recovery for interrupted SQL thread replication threads.

https://github.com/hcymysql/pt-slave-repair

Comment: HI hiller, it may be that this is your site.  If it is, you need to declare that in your answer.

Comment: Connect to the slave database where the synchronization error occurred and execute the following command using a MySQL replication account, such as 'repl', with appropriate permissions granted for running the tool.

Repair repl error:

shell> chmod 755 pt-slave-repair
shell> ./pt-slave-repair -H slaveIp -P 3306 -u repl -p 123456 -d yourDB

Answer (score 0):

## HOW TO BYPASS ALL DUPLICATE KEY ERRORS

There are two ways to bypass duplicate key errors

### METHOD #1 : Configure it in `my.cnf`

Add this line under the `[mysqld]` group header in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
slave-skip-errors=1062
```

then restart mysql.

Once replication begins, all duplicate key errors will be bypassed. Once `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0, you are all caught up. However, the data on the Slave is out-of-sync with the Master. What do you do next ???

### METHOD #2 : Use an Automated Tool

I  am sure you don't have the time to run

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;
START SLAVE;
```

over and over again. Wouldn't it be nice if an automated tool can do that for you ? Well, such a tool exists. It's called [`pt-slave-restart`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-slave-restart.html).

You would run it something like this:

```
pt-slave-restart --error-numbers 1062
```

Put this in a crontab to go off every minute.

```
* * * * * pt-slave-restart --error-numbers 1062
```

Even better, you can make a server daemon and not use a crontab

```
pt-slave-restart --error-numbers 1062 --daemonize
```

and you do not need to restart mysqld.

Either way, [`pt-slave-restart`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-slave-restart.html) will skip that error over and over again until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0. When you are done having the Slave get caught up, stop using [`pt-slave-restart`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-slave-restart.html).

However, you still have the same problem as **METHOD #1**: the data on the Slave is out-of-sync with the Master. What do you do next ???

## OK, WHAT DO YOU DO NEXT ???

You must synchronize the data on the Slave with your Master. Wouldn't it be nice if a utility exists that can do that for you ? Well, such a tool exists. In fact, there are two tools. They are called [`pt-table-checksum`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html) and [`pt-table-sync`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html).

What do they do ???

You use [`pt-table-checksum`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html) to check on MySQL replication integrity. If you encounter any table that have different checksums between Master and Slave, such a table on the Slave is out-of-sync.

You use [`pt-table-sync`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) to synchronize MySQL table data.

You can run

```
pt-table-sync --print > sync_file.txt
```

to see what will change (this is like a dry run of the real thing)

You then run

```
pt-table-sync --execute
```

to perform the actual sync.

## PLEASE READ THE PERCONA TOOLKIT DOCUMENTATION.

## ALWAYS HANDLE PERCONA TOOLKIT RESPONSIBLY !!!

NOTE : Sadly, there is absolutely nothing you can with MySQL 5.5 and GTID.

Answer (score 0):

If the master DB is not that huge, I would rebuild it. you can either use logical backup like mysqldump or physical backup like percona xbackup --use a point in time dump so you can repoint the slave to master safely.